# S3A: fails while S3: works in Spark EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm using EMR 5.5.0 with Spark.  If I write a simple file to s3 using an `s3://...` URL it writes fine.  But if I use an `s3a://...` address, it fails with `Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied`

Using the AWS command line I'm able to cp, mv, and rm any file in the path I'm writing to.  But from spark, `s3a` fails on the put command.

We have Server Side Encryption Enabled, and I know spark knows because the `s3` URLs work.  Any ideas?

Failed PUT DEBUG logs [here](https://pastebin.com/B6KU5nPu).  Maybe its important to note, I'm doing an `rdd.saveAsTextFile(path)` but the put command says its trying to write to `/my-bucket/tmp/carlos/testWrite/4/_temporary/0/` which it should only do in parquet?  Not sure if that detail is relevant but thought I would mention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

s3a is the actively maintained S3 client in Apache Hadoop. AWS forked their own client off from the Apache s3n:// client many years ago & (presumably) have massively reworked theirs.

They can read and write the same data, but some bits of EMR expect extra methods in the filesystem client which only EMR s3 supports...you cannot safely use s3a.

There's also the original ASF s3:// client which is incompatible with everything else, but was the first code used to connect Hadoop with S3, way before EMR was a product from amazon.

Which is better? S3A is probably, as of Aug 2017, faster on aggressive read IO of columnar formats like ORC and Parquet. EMR S3, with emrfs probably has the edge in terms of resilience and consistency. But the open source ASF S3A client is moving to address those

Comment: Do you happen to know if the `EMR` `s3` protocol allows predicate pushdown in Parquet?  (Similar to how it allows it with `s3a`)

Comment: that's not at the FS level, it's between Spark & the Parquet lib. Depends on what AWS have done with those two projects & whatever settings are needed for pushdown. You're best off testing it to see

Answer (score 1):

Turns out EMR does not support `s3a` protocol at all as of today.  In addition, it says `s3` and `s3n` are interchangable, but you should use `s3`

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-file-system-s3/
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-file-systems.html

One thing to Note is that `s3a` although not supported, seems to work for reading, but not writing.

**Update May 29, 2018:**

Just to give a fuller answer, the s3a protocol *is* supported with s3+emr if you're using them with Databricks.

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html